# maxRecordsPerFile is not working in Azure Data Bricks

Tags: azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

```
df.write.option("header",True) \
        .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 100000) \
        .partitionBy("customer") \
        .mode("overwrite") \
        .csv("/mnt/Output/")
```

I am using the above pyspark script to split my big CSV file into small chunks based on the customer column.
I am using Azure Data Bricks.

maxRecordsPerFile option is not working and it creates multiple files under each customer folder, each file has less than 5K records.

How could I manage to control the record count? Or
How could I create only one file under each customer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`maxRecordsPerFile` is only applied at internal Spark partition level, so probably the parallelization done by Spark does not have more than 5k records, so your `100000` value is useless. Try with a coalesce to reduce the dataframe partitions before the write.

```
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header",True) \
    .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 100000) \
    .partitionBy("customer") \
    .mode("overwrite") \
    .csv("/mnt/Output/")
```