# repartition not working with xml file in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, spark-java

I have dataframe which I want to save as **multiple** xml files. This is my code:

```
 employees
                .repartition(col("first_name"))
                .write()
                .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 5)
                .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
                .partitionBy("first_name")
                .format("xml")
                .save("C:/spark_output/");
```

Im expecting output to see output like this:

```
spark_output/
  first_name=Alex
    part-00000.xml
    part-00001.xml
  first_name=Mike
    part-00000.xml
    part-00001.xml
  first_name=Nicole
    part-00000.xml
    part-00001.xml
```

But the output contains **only one file with 10 rows**.

I don't understand what is going on? How can I fix this?

Any advice would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [maxRecordsPerFile is not working in Azure Data Bricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74039387/maxrecordsperfile-is-not-working-in-azure-data-bricks)

Comment: @ZachKing no, the problem seems to be that repartitioning is not working with xml files.

Comment: why do you want to store data in xml files ? I believe xml files are not splittable & it will cause data loading performance.

Comment: @Srinivas we have a task to create sitemap from large dataset which contains 5m records, and we decided to use spark for that purpose

Answer (score 1):

`.partitionBy` is not supported for the spark-xml (Databricks' open source XML data sink) and does not appear to be on the roadmap for the project in GitHub

https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml/issues/327